# play 2 videoview overlap in one layout

Tags: android

I want to make 2 videoviews overlap in one layout like this

[image]

This my code:

```
private void PlayVideo() {
    try {
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(
                MainActivity.this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

        Uri video = Uri.parse(videourl);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        // videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                videoView.start();
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Video Play Error :" + e.toString());

        progressDialog.dismiss();

        System.out.println("Video Play Error :" + e.toString());
        finish();
    }
```

My problem is: video 1 can play, but video 2 not play. If I minimize my application and I maximize again, 2 videos can run at the same time.
Please help , thanks before!

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your issue. You mean: if you start both videos at the same time, then only one will start, and after minimizing and then bringing back to front, both videos play? I posted an answer that may solve part of your issue if that happens.

Comment: @Bloom did you find the solution?

Answer (score 5):

`VideView` is a surface view that should not overlay each other. The order of the components in the layout is not considered during rendering. The solution is to use the `setZOrderMediaOverlay()` method to inform the system that video2 is above any other surface. In your code I can't see video2 but you should include the following line in its initialization.

```
video2View.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
```